# I don't understand the k-means scipy algorithm

Tags: python, scipy, k-means

I'm trying to use the scipy kmeans algorithm.

So I have this really simple example:

```
from numpy import array
from scipy.cluster.vq import vq, kmeans, whiten
features  = array([[3,4],[3,5],[4,2],[4,2]])
book = array((features[0],features[2]))
final = kmeans(features,book)
```

and the result is

```
final
(array([[3, 4],
       [4, 2]]), 0.25)
```

What I don't understand is, for me the centroids coordinate should be the barycentre of all the points belongings to the cluster, so in this exemple

```
[3,9/2] and [4,2]
```

can anyone explain me the result the scipy algorithm is giving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is preserving the data type that you are giving it (int). Try:

```
features  = array([[3., 4.], [3., 5.], [4., 2.], [4., 2.]])
```